# Neo4j Auto indexing issues

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have tried auto indexing and have set my neo4j.properties file to the following:

```
# Autoindexing

# Enable auto-indexing for nodes, default is false
#node_auto_indexing=true

# The node property keys to be auto-indexed, if enabled
#node_keys_indexable=Name,Type,CurrentVersion,DateTimeCreated,CurrentVersionDateTime,VersionCount,  CustomerName,DocumentReference,Version
```

Before I had set `node_auto_indexing=true` to false and created my own index for testing but now I want to auto index all my node properties?

And When i run this cypher query it returns 0 rows?

```
start n = node:node_auto_index(Name = "Mike") return n;
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you create your nodes when node_auto_indexing was false? If so, these existing nodes won't be "automatically" indexed when you set the property to true. You will have to manually add them to the auto index ( http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/auto-indexing.html)

Note that any new nodes created node_auto_indexing=true will be indexed without manual intervention.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue with version 1.7-SNAPSHOT.

It seems there are 2 properties, one being a duplicate of the other:

```
node_autoindexing_enabled=true # Commented out in neo4j.properties - but has no effect
node_auto_indexing=true        # Not in the file at all, but when added did index new nodes
node_keys_indexable=name,_id
```

It seems the 2nd one enables indexing but the 1st one does not. Hopefully if this is a bug it will get addressed (or has been addressed since the version I downloaded).